# Dividing by 100 precision

Tags: c#, double, precision, divide

I'm working on something and I've got a problem which I do not understand.

```
double d = 95.24 / (double)100;
Console.Write(d); //Break point here
```

The console output is 0.9524 (as expected) but if I look to 'd' after stoped the program it returns 0.95239999999999991.

I have tried every cast possible and the result is the same.  The problem is I use 'd' elsewhere and this precision problem makes my program failed.

So why does it do that?  How can I fix it?

Comment: There are so many floating point number questions like that here on SO

Comment: Guessing the default format of Double.ToString shows only 4 first decimals. You should move to the decimal type if you want an exact representation (float and double are not exact representations)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

The short of it is that a floating-point number is stored in what amounts to base-2 scientific notation. There is an integer significand understood to have one place in front of a decimal point, which is raised to an integer power of two. This allows for the storage of numbers in a relatively compact format; the downside is that the conversion from base ten to base 2 and back can introduce error.

To mitigate this, whenever high precision at low magnitudes is required, use `decimal` instead of `double`; decimal is a 128-bit floating point number type designed to have very high precision, at the cost of reduced range (it can only represent numbers up to +- 79 nonillion, 7.9E28, instead of double's +- 1.8E308; still plenty for most non-astronomical, non-physics computer programs) and double the memory footprint of a double.

Answer (score 8):

Use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead of double.

Answer (score 2):

A very good article that describes a lot: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) It is not related to C#, but to the float arithmetic in general.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead:

```
decimal d = 95.24 / 100m;
Console.Write(d); //Break point here
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
double d = Math.Round(95.24/(double)100, 4);

Console.Write(d);
```

edit: Or use a decimal, yeah. I was just trying to keep the answer as similar to the question as possible :)